# PHP format price in variable

Tags: php, variables, formatting

I have a variable that contains a price. It however takes the 0 from the price if it has cents. Such as $9.5 instead of $9.50. But if the price is $9.00 I want to display it as just $9.

Cents will not be displayed that often so that is why I want to keep the dollar amounts short but there will be the odd case that I will have cents but it just adds the zeros onto the dollars when there are no cents.

How would I cater for both scenarios in my code?

```
foreach($av as $day => $a){
                            if(isset($price[$ro['Room']['id']][$r['Rate']['id']][$day])){   
                                $arr_total += $price[$ro['Room']['id']][$r['Rate']['id']][$day];
                            } else {
                                $errors[] = "No Set Price for $day";
                            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
number_format($price, !($price == (int)$price) * 2);
```

Examples:

```
$price = 9.01;
echo number_format($price, !($price == (int)$price) * 2);
// output: 9.01

$price = 9.00;
echo number_format($price, !($price == (int)$price) * 2);
// output: 9
```

Comment: +1 Logically I'm not sure I like multiplying a boolean, but this works perfectly.

Comment: Could always throw in another `(int)` cast but there's no need and, like you said, works just fine because it will always be cast properly for the multiplication.

Comment: This worked great thanks, I was puzzled on how to meet both conditions. This code amy run on a windows enviroment so this is the best option

Answer (score 3):

pseudo-pseudo code:

```
if ($thePrice == intval($thePrice))
    $thePrice = intval($thePrice);
else
    $thePrice = money_format('%i', $thePrice);
```

See [money_format()](http://us.php.net/money_format)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of core functions that may interest you

- The first is [`money_format();`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php). This function is perfectly suited for your purposes, but it won't work on Windows systems. If you can guarantee your code won't ever be used on Windows, I would use this.
- The second is [`number_format();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). Again, this function is well suited to your needs, but with the added advantage of being able to work on Windows. It doesn't, however, output formatted currency, but you can use it at least to get your decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Umm you simply try multiplying the number by 1. I THINK that might work, untested..

Comment: This will yield the same result as floatval() - trimming the 0 of .50.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the value from the database it will probably be a string so you just have to convert it to a floting point number.

```
floatval($price)
```

Comment: This will remove any trailing 0 "9.50" -> 9.5